# Deploying Winforms app to other users

Tags: winforms

I'm looking for a way to send a winforms project I've created to a friend. Can someone show me the easiest way (or example) to convert this thing into a .exe, if that is possible, so I can get this off my plate?

Comment: Why you not compile the project in VS and obtain the .exe?

Answer (score 0):

Check out clickonce application deployment It is very simple and gets the job done.  It isn't as customizable as a windows installer, but it still handles most of the basic needs, including updating an application.

This is a thorough guide: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t71a733d%28VS.80%29.aspx
This is a small tutorial, little old, but it should still apply: http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/37db1d/deploying-wpf-application-with-clickonce-deployment-techniques/